# can python skip value instead of providing None or False in case of condition fails in 'if expression'?

Tags: python

```
resources = [
  {
    name: 'xxxxx',
    type: 'linux'
  },
  {
    name: 'yyyyy',
    type: 'linux'
  },
  {
    name: 'zzzzz',
    type: 'windows'
  },
]
```

In my python script, I wanted to get linux resources from a list of all resources as in the above sample JSON. The following two lines of code met my expectation, but it needs to remove 'None' first by using filter, which creates another list.

`value = list((res if 'type' in res and res['type'] == 'linux' else None) for res in resources)`

as result, value returns list with None

```
[
  {
    name: 'xxxxx',
    type: 'linux'
  },
  {
    name: 'yyyyy',
    type: 'linux'
  },
  None
]
```

Thus, I used filter to remove None from the list.

`linux_resources = list(filter(None, value))`

In order to avoid handling None, I was thinking to use the condition `list(res ('type' in res and res['type'] == 'linux' and res) for res in resources)`, but it gives rather False in failed cases. Eventually no difference in these two (None and False) approaches.

Is there any best way, which skip None or False in failed condition and add objects only if condition met to the list, in a single line of code (short and crisp)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing an `... if ... else ...` ternary expression, put a condition in the list comprehension itself:

```py
value = [res for res in resources if 'type' in res and res['type'] == 'linux']
```

I used square brackets `[...]` instead of `list(...)` here because it's more natural, but you can use either way.

In this case, the condition `'type' in res and res['type'] == 'linux'` can also be simplified to `res.get('type') == 'linux'`, since the `get` method returns `None` (or another default value you provide) instead of raising a `KeyError` when the key is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, just do

```
value = [res for res in resources if res['type'] == 'linux']
```

Simple list comprehension.